# i want call attend after start the duration when call cut to get the total duration

Tags: android, eclipse

i want to get correct duration for this code i get duration this code using but when i call action start example outgoing call when i call button click to start the time also when i call cut the process to get duration total duration but i want when call attend to start the time duration to stop call get correct duration how to get this my code

```
//public class CallDurationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
DatabaseHandler db;

// instance variables of sharedpreferences
SharedPreferences mSharedPrefernce;
Editor e;

// String variables for number,date,time,calltype
String number = "";
String date = "";
String time = "";
String calltype = "";
String totime = "";
long startTime, endTime;

CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(180000,1000);

String hms;
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    db = new DatabaseHandler(context);



   // Log.v("info", "calls info....");

    // initialising the sharedpreferences
    mSharedPrefernce = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
    e = mSharedPrefernce.edit();

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle == null)
        return;

    // initialising the variables
    number = null;
    startTime = 0;
    endTime = 0;

    // getting incoming call details
    String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    if ((state != null)
            && (state
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))) {

       // Log.v("info", "Phone Ringing..");

        number = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
       // Log.v("info", "Incomng Number: " + number);

        calltype = "Incoming";

        Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
        today.setToNow();

        date = today.monthDay + "-" + (today.month + 1) + "-" + today.year;
        time = today.format("%k:%M:%S");

        // putting the values into the SharedPreferences
        e.putString("number", number);
        e.putString("Type", calltype);
        e.putString("date", date);
        e.putString("time", time);
        e.commit();
        db.addContact(new PhoneNumberDetails(number,date,time,null,calltype));
        Toast.makeText(context,"Detect Calls sample application\nIncoming number: "+ number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        db.addContact(new PhoneNumberDetails(number, date, time, "duration", calltype));
    }
    // getting outgoing call details
    else if (state == null) {
        number = bundle.getString(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

       // Log.v("info", "Outgoing Number: " + number);

        calltype = "Outgoing";

        Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
        today.setToNow();

        date = today.monthDay + "-" + (today.month + 1) + "-" + today.year;
       // Log.v("date Info","date:" + date);

        time = today.format("%k:%M:%S");
        Log.v("time Info","time:" + time);

        // putting the values into the SharedPreferences
        e.putString("number", number);
        e.putString("Type", calltype);
        e.putString("date", date);
        e.putString("time", time);
        e.commit();

        Toast.makeText(context,"Detect Calls sample application\nOutgoing number: "+ number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       //db.addContact(new PhoneNumberDetails(number, date, time, "totime",calltype));

    }
    // called when the call is answered
    else if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
        Log.v("info", "Call Ansered..");

        timer.start();

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        e.putLong("start", startTime);
        e.commit();

    } 
    // called when the call is ended
    else if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
        Log.v("info", "Call Ended..");

        timer.cancel();

        Log.v("Time", ""+hms);

        Toast.makeText(context, hms, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        String phonenumber=null, type=null, date1=null, time1=null,  duration=null;

        // getting the values from the SharedPreferences
        phonenumber = mSharedPrefernce.getString("number","");
        type = mSharedPrefernce.getString("Type", "");
        date1 = mSharedPrefernce.getString("date", "");
        time1 = mSharedPrefernce.getString("time", "");
        long start=0;
        start = mSharedPrefernce.getLong("start", 0);
        Log.v("info", "startTime=" + start);

        // clearing the SharedPreferences
        mSharedPrefernce.edit().clear();

        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.v("info", "endTime=" + endTime);
        long totalTime =0;
        totalTime = endTime - start;
        String totime=Long.toString(0); 
        long result=Long.parseLong(totime);
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH':'mm':'ss");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0"));

        duration = df.format(new Date(totalTime));


       db.addContact(new PhoneNumberDetails(phonenumber, date1, time1, duration, type));

       System.out.println("GOT SOMETHING - "+phonenumber + " " + date1 + " " + time1 + " " + duration + " " + type);

        Log.d("testing","" +phonenumber);

        Toast.makeText(context, phonenumber + " " + date1 + " " + time1 + " " + duration + " " + type, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

}

public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {  
     public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {  
          super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);  
     }  
     @Override  
    public void onFinish() {  

    }  

     @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override  
     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {  
           long millis = millisUntilFinished;  
            hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),  
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),  
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));  
            System.out.println(hms);  
            Log.v("Timing", hms);
     }  
}
```

}

Comment: Extremely difficult to understand your problem... I've tried to edit it, but I was not sure if I would change your question. Please be more specific and more pay more attention to the language. I would be grateful to help you

Comment: how to get correct call duration sir i am using above method i did t get him sir